# Merge a new Rx.Observable after a previous one got the first set of data

Tags: javascript, reactive-programming, rxjs

I am working on creating a infinite scroll table using data received from Json requests.
The problem is I need to add the scroll observable only after the first response from the promise.

```
    //Set Observables
var column = this.refs.column;
var columnScrollStream = Rx.Observable.fromEvent(column, 'scroll').filter(function () {
  return (column.scrollHeight - column.scrollTop == columnHeight);
});

var refreshTimeStream = Rx.Observable.timer(0, 30000);

var columnScrollSubscription = columnScrollStream.subscribe(function (scroll) {
  paginationNo += 10;
});

//Merge Observables
var requestStream = Rx.Observable
  .merge(refreshTimeStream, columnScrollStream)
  .map(function() {
      return url+'/0/'+paginationNo;
  };

// Use Observables
var responseStream = requestStream
  .throttle(400).flatMapLatest(function(requestUrl) {
    return Rx.Observable.fromPromise(jQuery.getJSON(requestUrl));
  });

//Use result   
this.subscription = responseStream.subscribe(function(result) {
  /* use result here*/
  /* !!! Place where the scoll Observable should be, because the column ref gets created only after the result is delivered */
```

Comment: I'm not sure what you're trying to do, but `take(1)` will help you only take the first event.

Comment: Thank you kakigoori, you are right take(1) or .first() only take the first event and dispose of the subscription after that.

Comment: What I am trying to do is to have a first set of data (from the promise), an after that add the scroll and timer as observables (streams) and get new data each time.
The code above works great if i have the wrapper outside the data, but I need to add the wrapper after I get the first response.

Comment: Is it possible `Rx.Observable.of('initial load')` added to your merge like `.merge(refreshTimeStream, columnScrollStream, Rx.Observable.of('initial load'))` would help you? It sounds like you want something to trigger your initial load as part of your requestStream.

Comment: Thank you Gloopy, sounds like exactly what I need. Hope it works.